# combine two files side by side with special condition

Tags: bash, awk, paste

sorry for the bad title folks ,  i dont how how to describe except with example.

so here we go , i have to files like these :

file 1 :

```
left1
left2
left3
```

file 2

```
right1
right2
right3
```

expected output :

```
left1 right1
right2 left2
left3 right3
```

i know we can use paste command to combine those two files side by side , but i dont know ow to make it like output above .

```
root@s132496:~# paste -d ' ' file1 file2
left1 right1
left2 right2
left3 right3
```

i read man paste but still cant figure out yet how to. please help me solve this , been working since morning with no luck.

thank you before folks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, if is always 2nd line and 2 fields which needs to be interchanged? or any more conditions are there, kindly elaborate on same.

Comment: Pipe what you have into `awk` and print fields back-to-front if line number is even.

Comment: hi , lines is vary not same for all files , but fields will always be the same

Comment: @RoyAjaRoyAja, you mean multiple lines will be there which you need to interchange their values? If yes then how do we rectify(is there any logic) to find out them or you simply want to give line numbers in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't told us that how many fields do you have in your Input_files and do we need to do interchange always 2nd line's fields etc things, so posting this by seeing your samples only.

```
paste -d" " file1 file2 | awk 'FNR==2{$0=$2 OFS $1} 1'
```

Comment: hi , that is only example files , and i cant say how much because it's vary

Comment: @RoyAjaRoyAja, then please do mention all the possible conditions of your requirement so that we could help you in a single time, kindly update your posts with some examples which are near to actual data.

Comment: so basically i generate output from my server , so the lines number is not always the same

Comment: @RoyAjaRoyAja, you could up-vote when you have repo with you not an issue, but try to adopt a habit of  selecting any of the answers as correct answer after sometime to close the question completely.

Answer (score 2):

With awk you could do something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}FNR%2{print $0, a[FNR];next}{print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
```

Expanded:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {        # For first input file (file1)
       a[FNR] = $0      # Store the current line in a new entry in array a
       next             # and skip to the next record
     }
     FNR % 2 {          # If the line number is odd
       print $0, a[FNR] # print in one order
       next             # and skip to the next record
     }
     {                  # for the rest lines (file2 even lines)
       print a[FNR], $0 # print in opposite order
     }' file1 file2
```

The assumption here is that `file1` is small enough to fit in memory, otherwise use cut and pipe to awk, but that will only work if you don't have spaces in the lines of file1 and file2.

Comment: thank you verified this is working method also , thank you for your hard work man